# Surmise in conclusion of essay

Tags: word-usage

Can we use "surmise" as follows in the conclusion section of an essay:

> To surmise my aforementioned thoughts, [a summary of the essay].

Generally, this statement is written as follows:

> To summarise my aforementioned thoughts, [a summary of the essay].

Since **surmise** means **deducing a conclusion** from available but incomplete facts which are not sufficient to act as evidence. So, through this conclusion statement, I want to convey that from the ideas that I have mentioned in the previous paragraphs of the essay, I have **deduced** the **[summary of the essay]**.

Comment: A *surmise* is marked as an uncertain guess, not a definite or even fairly strong conclusion. It has nothing to do with *summary*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As StoneyB mentions in his comment, "surmise" is a fancy way to say "guess".  It has nothing to do with "summarize".

> I **surmise** that you checked only one dictionary for the definition of "surmise".

Comment: I checked the dictionaries, but one of my friend who is an English teacher told me that the phrase "To surmise my thoughts" is often used in essays. So, I thought that I am not interpreting the meaning of "surmise" properly. I suggested him that "surmise" can't be a replacement of summary. Secondly, the phrase should be "To surmise from my thoughts' to mean "To deduce/guess from my thoughts".

Comment: Ah. Well I surmise you either misheard your friend, or your friend mislearned what surmise meant. It happens -- not every native speaker is perfect.  I'm still learning new words all the time.